Jenkins pipeline fails to establish a connection with Plastic SCM for the checkout stage
I am creating a CI/CD pipeline for an unreal engine project using jenkins and Plastic SCM on an EC2 Machine.
I have installed the plastic scm plugin in jenkins and I am trying to connect to pull the project to build it. but when I enter the credentials for the checkout it gives me an error:
The cm command 'd:\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\plasticscm-cli\Default\cm.exe repo list [repo@cloud] --server=[repo@cloud] --workingmode=UPWorkingMode --username=[username] ******' failed after 3 retries
I tried that command on a local terminal. it works.
the account is newly created and added to the unity organization. I have triple checked the credentials and even tried using the global client.conf the result is it still works locally but not in the pipeline.
I tried setting up another project using git and it worked. the problem appears to be related to plasticSCM or its plugin.
